# Should I sign (with a public/private key) a form based authentication (no SSL)?

Tags: authentication

I want to do a form based authentication.
Should I sign (with a public/private key) a form based authentication (with no SSL)?

I know it will not avoid a middle man attack, but at least it will secure the value of the password if I hide it in the signature.

Is it useless to sign a form authentication? What are the best ways to authenticate without SSL?

Do places like Heroku provide SSL for free? I am just playing around and trying to learn cool stuff, don't want to pay :(

**[UPDATE]**:
In a very concise way I want to start and maintain a simple session with minimal security through HTTP. How can I do that? The main requirement is to avoid an unauthenticated user from doing requests to the REST API that might change something on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you own the client and the server, and hence can trivially share a secret between them (i.e. some number of random bytes), and notwithstanding the issues of keeping that secret secret, then, assuming that you're using REST such that HTTP request parameters are in the URL and not in the body:

- Invent a shared secret. We'll call this K. For example, generate 128 random bits:

  dd if=/dev/random bs=16 count=1 | od -t x1

  (Are 128 bits necessary / sufficient? Depends on your requirements...)
- With each request:

  - Generate a nonce N. This is either:

    - A random number.
    - A timestamp: seconds-since-epoch / time-window-size
      We'll come back to time window size.
  - Add the nonce as a request parameter:

    http://foo.com/blah/blah?x=y@mood=dismal?N=0x123456789abcdef
  - Compute a string S containing:

    - The HTTP method, e.g. GET, POST.
    - The complete URL.
  - Compute an HMAC where:

    - K is the key
    - The text (i.e. stuff being HMACed) is S.
  - Append the HMAC as a request parameters.
- On the server:

  - Strip the HMAC from the request.
  - Extract N from the request.
  - Validate N (see below).
  - Compute S as above.
  - Find the client's K.
  - Compute the HMAC as above.
  - Compare computed HMAC with the one from the request.

That means that:

- I have to know K to send a request.
- An attacker can't modify the request URL in flight, since that would invalidate the HMAC.

However, an observer can capture and replay the request. That's where the nonce comes in:

- If you use a time-based nonce then

  - The request can be replayed within the time window.
  - The time window must be large enough to accommodate clock differences between client and server, and the network latency.
  - "Validation" means that the server must check the timestamp to ensure that it's "now".
- If you use a random nonce then the server must remember historic nonces and reject any new requests with previously-seen nonces.
- Better: use a time window /and/ a random number. The server then just remembers nonces within the current time window.

Of course, this needs synchronised clocks and a decent source of random numbers, and doesn't provide confidentiality...

Comment: Thanks :)
 That is a really good answer, it leaves a lot of stuff for me study  and learn a little bit more.
 I got it that I wasn't specific enough, I'll try to be more specific on the next questions ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think that you're essentially asking how to prove knowledge of a shared secret (i.e. username/password) to the server over an unencrypted HTTP connection?

Basic rule 1: don't roll your own crypto[graphic protocols]: if you need confidentiality and integrity (i.e. encryption and authentication, amongst other things) then use TLS/SSL, unless you're smart/knowledgeable/experienced enough to do it yourself.

Basic rule 2: don't enumerate algorithms/techniques (such as public key cryptography) and ask whether they'll solve your problem, without first understanding your security requirements. Cryptographic algorithms provide security properties like confidentiality. Security requirements end up (following some analysis) depending upon certain such properties. Appropriate techniques therefore drop out from an security requirements/analysis exercise, rather than the other way round.

To answer your direct question: no, because you've just replaced one secret with another (and hence not solved your problem), not considered replay attacks, and not considered things like confused deputies and connection hijacking.

If you still want to roll your own then first figure out your security requirements: you're trying to authenticate the client (i.e. browser) to the server, but does the server have to prove its identity to the client? *Why* are you authenticating? If it's to grant access to certain information, then why are you then promptly sending that information in the clear having authenticated? (A MITM isn't the same as a passive observer.) Do some threat modelling. Assuming that you're OK with all that, you'll probably end up inventing something that looks like an HMAC with either time or server-side state to prevent replays. You'd still have the problem of either sharing a secret or agreeing upon a trusted third party though.

Comment: Thank you :)
 Those are 2 good rules to follow, and I get your perspective, you're right.
 I want to make a simple login for a hobby project, so I don't want to pay for any SSL certificate. At the same time it doesn't make much sense to send a clear password through a post, how can I avoid that.
 In a very concise way I want to start and maintain a simple session with minimal security through HTTP. How can I do that?
 The main requirement is to avoid an unauthenticated user from doing requests to the REST API that might change something on the server.